# How to call parse_args() twice on the same set of arguments in Python's argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Simplified test case:
I have a script that takes two arguments. The first is a list of integers. The second is a single integer that must be contained in the first argument's set of integers.

For example:

```
$ python argtest.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 2
```

Should work, but:

```
$ python argtest.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 4
```

Should not work, since `num` is not `in` `valid_nums`. However, I have had some difficulty (read: I suspect it is more trouble than it's worth, but I really want it to work) implementing this functionality.

Implementation attempt:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--valid_nums',
                    type=int,
                    nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
print "Numbers: ", args.valid_nums


parser.add_argument('--num',
                    type=int,
                    choices=args.valid_nums)

args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Actual output:

```
$ python argtesttest.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 2
usage: argtesttest.py [-h] [--valid_nums VALID_NUMS [VALID_NUMS ...]]
argtesttest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --num 2
```

Desired output:

```
$ python argtesttest.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 2
Namespace(num=2, valid_nums=[1, 2, 3])
```

Now, (I think) the issue here is that I cannot add a new argument to the parser after I have called `parse_args()`, which yields the error about an unrecognized argument, but I can't think of a way around it. Is there any way to break up the processing of arguments such that it isn't all at once?

Obviously this would be pretty trivial to do if I only called `parse_args()` once and handled the container membership checking myself, but I'd like to get it working 'natively' using `argparse`'s built-in error-checking.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's the first `parse_args` call that is raising the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to use `parser.parse_known_args()` as opposed to `parser.parse_args()`, or add all the arguments to parser before calling `parse_args()`.

`parse_args()` needs to understand all the current arguments in `sys.argv`, which already contains `--num` at the time of first parsing, hence the exception.

Comment: Ugh, not sure how I missed that in the docs. Anyway, thanks; that works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with namespace and parse_known_args, and call parse_args at the end

```
class UserNamespace(object):
    pass
user_namespace = UserNamespace()

p = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
p.add_argument('-c', '--config', dest='config', default='')
p.parse_known_args(namespace=user_namespace)
if user_namespace.config == '':
    p.add_argument('-w', '--whatever', dest='whatever', default='')

parsed_args = p.parse_args(namespace=user_namespace)
```

for the specific case:

num.py:

```
import argparse
class UserNamespace(object):
    pass
user_namespace = UserNamespace()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--valid_nums', dest='valid_nums',
                    type=int,
                    nargs='+')

parser.parse_known_args(namespace=user_namespace)

parser.add_argument('--num',
                    type=int,
                    choices=user_namespace.valid_nums)

args = parser.parse_args(namespace=user_namespace)

print "Numbers: ", user_namespace.valid_nums
```

so you call:

```
$python num.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 2  
Numbers:  [1, 2, 3]

$python num.py --valid_nums 1 2 3 --num 4  
usage: num.py [-h] [--valid_nums VALID_NUMS [VALID_NUMS ...]] [--num {1,2,3}]
num.py: error: argument --num: invalid choice: 4 (choose from 1, 2, 3)
```

references : 
[argparse namespace](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace)
[argparse parse_known_args](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args)

bye!

Update March 4 2017
Better to instantiate the UserNamespace, or other functionalities (like add_subparsers) could not work properly.