# How can I tell argparse not to exit if there are not enough args?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to extend argparse to work with configuration files as well as CLI arguments. I want to pass in all the options from the config files *but* not exit if there are unknown options.

My idea was to first call `parse_known_args` on the new options, then call
`parse_known_args` again with `sys.argv`. That allows me to warn about exactly the unknown options from the configuration files, not the ones on the CLI. However, argparse exits after the first call to `parse_known_args` if there are not enough arguments. Is there a way to tell it not to exit?

My code looks like this:

```py
class Parser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        config = {}
        for file in get_config_files(self.prog):
            for key, value in try_parse(file, self.default_ext).items():
                config[key] = value, file

        new_args = []
        for key, (val, _) in config.items():
            new_args.append('--' + key)
            new_args.append(val)

        # override configuration with argparse's builtin parsing
        # makes CLI options take precedence over config files
        # ----- This is where argparse exits -----
        parsed_config, unknown = super().parse_known_args(new_args, namespace)
        #print("finished first call to known_args")

        for key in unknown[::2]:
            key = key[2:]
            _, filename = config[key]
            warnings.warn("unknown option '%s' (from %s)" % (key, filename))
        #print(parsed_config)

        return super().parse_known_args(args, parsed_config)
```

And an example usage would look like this:

```py
>>> from pyautoconfig import Parser
>>> p = Parser(prog='test')
>>> p.add_argument('positional')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='positional', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> p.parse_args(['positional arg'])
usage: test [-h] positional
test: error: the following arguments are required: positional
```

Note how it exits with an error even though I passed a positional argument. How can I avoid this?

I found [How to call parse_args() twice on the same set of arguments in Python's argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362008/how-to-call-parse-args-twice-on-the-same-set-of-arguments-in-pythons-argparse), but that deals with too many args, not too few (the recommended solution is use `parse_known_args`).

The full code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jyn514/py-autoconfig/tree/external-interface) if that helps.

Comment: I looked at the source code and I can't even catch ArgumentError because `parse_known_args` swallows that and exits first: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L1799 :(

Comment: You may be falling into the "XY Problem" here.  I'd re-think what you are trying to do: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem  In other words: try using a different tool to parse a configuration file, not something meant for command-line arguments.

Comment: @KevinAnderson the problem is I want to keep all the features of argparse, like `type` and `mutually_exclusive_args` and `choices`. I'm not trying to make argparse parse JSON or anything like that, I'm doing all that myself.

Comment: You can change behavior when the parser encounters an error.  `parser.error` and `parser.exit` can be customized.  Note that the `required_actions` case uses `self.error(....)`.

Comment: @hpaulj This did not work because it does not check for mutually exclusive arguments. Note in the source that check comes after the check for required arguments: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L2038. Additionally, I don't want to catch every error, only this particular one.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue29670#msg288990 - One refactoring that I've explored is moving all the `self.error` calls out of `_parse_known_args`, and into `parse_known_args`.  This give users more control over how errors are handled.

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue26394 looks somewhat similar to what I want, although I would also like to set optional arguments if they were not present in the CLI args.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack! Argparse only throws the error if there are required actions which are not present: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L2033. So, if no actions are required, no error is thrown.

New code:

```py
        # HACK: make all these not required to avoid argparse exiting
        # HACK: if there are too few args
        temp_actions = []
        for action in self._actions:
            if action.required:
                action.required = False
                temp_actions.append(action)
        parsed_config, unknown = super().parse_known_args(new_args, namespace)

        # HACK: reset the actions to their previous state
        for action in temp_actions:
            action.required = True
```